# How to write to crontab without writing to a temp file using PHP

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP code that writes cronjobs into crontab using this code.

```
        $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');

        file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output . $command . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
        exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

It works 100% well. But issue is that lots of users would accessing the application so won't files will be over-written? if not over-written I am sure there would be some other issue.

My question is how do I write/append to crontab using single command without writing that cron contents to temp file?

I tried something like `echo "cron here" > crontab` but didn't work.

Comment: if multiple users may use this code at the same time, you may try to make it thread-safe, so adding the session-id to the name of the .txt file ? But you're right, there must be a solution not to use any temp file :)

Comment: read file using `file_get_content` then only rewrite into the file?

Comment: @Random Yes I prefer a single BASH/Shell command to do that. instead of writing a temp file.

Comment: If you have to do it using PHP .. Use a guaranteed unique filename : string tempnam ( string $dir , string $prefix ), from http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php. At least then the files wont get confused/overwritten, although you still have the issue of updating cron in a threaded fashion - one user may overwrite the changes made by another user 1 ms ago.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest, but how many times can these concurence edit occur to crontab? I would prefer some kind of locking mechanism for this case. For example create .lock file when user opens the file and delete the .lock file after editing is done. If another user will want to edit the crontab and .lock will be present, he won't be allowed.

Comment: the 2-line process is kinda short to run, so you would have the same concurence problem using a .lock file, if 2 users write the .lock file at the same time...

Comment: @Random you are right ... I am still thinking about a solution :P

Comment: I didn't mean to .lock only the operation of importing /tmp/crontab.txt, but the whole cron editing process (if I understood it right) in the mentioned application. How do you want to manage the situation when, for example 20 users, will add the same thing?